# How to make shell script run each command asynchronously

Tags: shell

I want to do an npm install in a ton of directories.

Can I create a shell script that will run `npm install` in all of them asynchronously? So I don't have to wait long for all of them to be done?

IE

`cd foo; npm install; cd ..;
cd bar; npm install; cd ..;
etc.`

Comment: `start npm install`, basically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run them in the background using `&` at the end:

```
cd foo && npm install &
cd bar && npm install &
```

There's no need for `cd ..` here because each line runs in a separate child process.
Also I'm using `&&` here instead of `;`, otherwise you'd need to add `()` to group the commands:

```
( cd foo; npm install ) &
( cd bar; npm install ) &
```

As a plus, `&&` will not execute commands to it's right if the command to it's left fails.